# Regex to check if a modifier is called

Tags: regex

I need a regex if a specific modifier is called.
Given:

```
    Object()
        .modifierA()
        .modifierB()
        .modifierC()
```

I want to check whenever a modifierD is not being used after the Object() call so the linter can warm me.

Is there a way of achieving this by regex?

As far I got

> \sObject(.*)((?!\s*.modifierD(.*\n)\s*..*\n)+

that works if the modifier is called as first:

```
    Object()
        .modifierD() 
        .modifierA()
```

so the linter will give me a correct warning here:

```
    Object()
        .modifierA()
        .modifierB()
        .modifierC()
```

but if another modifier is called first the regex is triggering the linter warning as well:

```
    Object()
        .modifierA()
        .modifierD()  
        .modifierB()
```

Is there a way to restrict the regex for my case?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a match, there should be a point to indicate what it end of the match is.

In this case it could match until there is no following line with .modifier, and until that point there should be no line matched with .modifierD to get in an indication that it was not matched.

```
\sObject\([^()]*\)(?:\n[^\S\n]*\.modifier[ABCE-F]\([^()]*\))+(?!\n[^\S\n]*\.modifier)
```

In parts, the pattern matches:

- `\sObject\([^()]*\)` Match a whitespace char, `Object` and from an opening till closing parenthesis
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\n[^\S\n]*` Match a newline, and optional whitespace chars without a newline
  - `\.modifier[ABCE-F]\([^()]*\)` Match .modifier and a char A-Z without the D followed matching from an opening till closing parenthesis
- `)+` Close non capture group and repeat it 1+ times to match at least 1 line that contains .modifier
- `(?!\n[^\S\n]*\.modifier)` Negative lookahead, assert not .modifier on the next line

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uNAPlJ/1)